# インクルードパスがうまく動かない

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

**前提・実現したいこと**
以前PHPで作成されていたあるコーポレートサイトをローカル環境で動かすために、xampp環境下で適応させようとしたところ、下記のエラーが発生しております。
もともと、config.incでインクルードパスを設定しておりました。
インクルードパスを正常に動かすか、直接参照させるかどちらでもよいので、解決方法を教えていただきたいです。

**構造**

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/test/data/shop_search.php
c:/xampp/htdocs/test/lib/config.inc
c:/xampp/htdocs/test/lib/Classes/PEAR/Pager.php
c:/xampp/php/PEAR
c:/xampp/php/php.ini
```

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

```
Warning: require_once(PEAR/Pager.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\data\shop_search.php on line 16

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PEAR/Pager.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR:C:/xampp/htdocs/test/lib:C:/xampp/htdocs/test/lib/Classes:C:/xampp/htdocs/test/lib/Classes/PEAR:') in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\data\shop_search.php on line 16
```

```
//shop_search.php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../lib/config.inc';
require_once 'PEAR/Pager.php';
```

```
# php.ini
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
include_path=C:\xampp\php\PEAR
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
```

```
//config.inc
define('USER_PATH',  'C:/xampp/htdocs/' . (DEBUG_MODE ? 'test' : 'www'));
$path = get_include_path() . ':' . USER_PATH . '/lib:'
    . USER_PATH . '/lib/Classes:' . USER_PATH . '/lib/Classes/PEAR:';
set_include_path($path);
```

**試したこと**
xamppのインクルードパスを消して直接参照しようとしましたが、`;`を`php.ini`の該当行に入れてみても、
`".:c:/php/pear/"`がインクルードパスとして必ず参照されました。
また、php.iniなどを書き換えたタイミングでapacheの再起動はしております。

**バージョン**

- PHP 7.4
- Apache 2.4
- XAMPP 3.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows環境の場合、;で区切るとのことで、PATH_SEPARATOR定数で連結したところ、パスが通りました。

下記、修正内容を記載します。

```
//config.inc
$path = USER_PATH . '/lib/Classes;'. USER_PATH . '/lib;' . USER_PATH . '/lib/Classes/PEAR;';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```